# Show $f$ is constant when $\forall h>0$, $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(y+h)-f(y) \leq f(y)-f(y-h)$.

Tags: real-analysis

For $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f''(x) \leq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$, $\forall h>0$, $f(y+h)-f(y) \leq f(y)-f(y-h)$.

Show "$f$ is a bounded below, then $f$ is constant function."

I'm trying to prove $f$ is a constant. But I don't have any idea how to approach those. Would you please give me any ideas or solutions?

Comment: @geetha290krm If $f''\leq 0$, the inequality holds. But the question is showing f is constant If $ f$ does hold property either that inequality or $f''\leq 0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function bounded below, with negative 2nd derivative. Show function is constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151524/function-bounded-below-with-negative-2nd-derivative-show-function-is-constant)

Comment: A solution can be found in the link on the right pane of this page. Please  do check for duplicates before posting a question.